# Ordering by date in Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am iterating over a set of objects in Ruby on Rails like so :

```
  <% @subject.Association.each do |horse| %>
 <tr>
  <td>
    <%= horse['Name'].to_s %>
    <%= horse['Size'] %>
  </td>
  </tr>
   <% end %>
```

The horse object has a date field, called dateRode.

I would like to order by this field.

I am not a ruby developer, but I tried a number of ways to do this resulting in only syntax errors e.g

```
<% subject.association.each do |horse|-> { order by "dateRode" DESC } %>
```

How can I do this in my code without editing ActiveRecords etc?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can order collection with `order` method like this:

```
<% @subject.Association.order(dateRode: :desc).each do |horse| %>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <%= horse['Name'].to_s %>
      <%= horse['Size'] %>
    </td>
  </tr>
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to replace this:

```
<% @subject.Association.each do |horse| %>
```

with

```
<% @subject.Association.order(dateRode: :desc).each do |horse| %>
```

Hoping that it would help you.

Answer (score 1):

```
<% subject.association.each do |horse|-> { order by "dateRode" DESC } %>
```

The above is a mix of erb and sql which isnt going to work.

The best way to do it is to create a scope in the model which is called by the controller.

model

```
def self.order_by_date_rode
    Model.includes(:association).order("associations.dateRode desc")
end
```

where Model is the name of your model and association is the name of the association you want to order by.

controller method

```
def some_method
  @subject = Model.order_by_date_rode
end
```

A less recommended way is to do the sorting in the view

```
<% @subject.Association.order(dateRode: :desc).each do |horse| %>
```

Answer (score 0):

the another way is that you can set a default scope for ordering of the association model like below

```
class Association < ActiveRecord::Base
  default_scope { order('dateRode DESC') }
end
```

so when you do `<% @subject.Association` it will automatically sort